# Is there an identity for dividing a function's derivative by the function itself?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential-geometry

Given $f(x)$, we know that $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} =\frac{d}{dx} \ln(f(x))$.  Is there any similar identity known if the denominator
happens to be raised to some power?  For example: $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^{2}}$ 
 or $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^{17}}$ ?

Comment: Let $u =f(x)$ and...

Comment: Also, you mean to say $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{d}{dx}\ln (f(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

When you say $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{d}{dx} \ln (f(x))$ you could equally as well be expressing an integral (and you can insert some additional absolute value bars if so inclined).  In much the same way you can answer your question for $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^n}$ for $n \neq 1$.  With $u=f(x)$ we have $du = f'(x) dx$ and so
$$
\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^n} \ dx = \int \frac{1}{u^n} \ du = - \frac{1}{n-1} u ^{-n+1}+C = - \frac{1}{n-1} \frac{1}{f(x)^{n-1}} + C.
$$ 
So, I guess, if you wanted a relation among derivatives you could say
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{1}{1-n} \frac{1}{f(x)^{n-1}} \right)=  \frac{f'(x)} {f(x)^n}, \text{ when }n \neq 1.
$$